# Methods to sample a 2-dim curve efficiently

Tags: algorithm

I would like to ask for an efficient method / algorithm to sample a 2-dim curve with the following criteria. The curve is guaranteed not to cross itself.

1. The number of points should be minimized;
2. The sample curve, which connects all the sample points together with lines, should resemble the original one.

For example, since sample points are connected with lines, a line should then be sampled with just two points on both ends. But for an arc, there are more points along it to make the sample curve accurate enough.

Comment: How is your curve represented?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie It is extracted from svg file. Currently I have such a library function to know the coordinates of any point on the curve given the curve length from the starting point. The library is [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svg.path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to simplify polyline, constructed from given points, with [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker), then build some kind of smooth curve through reduced point set.

To make smooth curve, you can use splines (e.g. Catmull-Rom) or [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691499/how-do-i-draw-a-closed-curve-over-a-set-of-points) (intended for closed curves, but might be adapted for open ones)

Comment: DP algorithm works with this problem. Just FYI, Douglas-Peucker works pretty well only for "piecewise" curves, which I define as the curves with obvious characteristics of segmentation.